# How do I Add a timestamp to a git clone for a Filemaker file?

Tags: git, filemaker

A rather odd application I suppose...but how can I add a timestamp to git clone for a Filemaker file.

Ideal on my MAC I'd like to use something like:

```
sudo git clone -l -s -n . ../Dev_copy_[date_time]
```

I've tried the follow:

```
sudo git clone -l -s -n . ../Dev_copy_date_+%F_%T
```

But it give me a literal clone

```
 "Dev_copy_date_+%F_%T"
```

Comment: Why are you using `sudo` with Git? There's almost never a good reason to do that.

Comment: Also, why are you cloning a local copy (`.`) to another local copy (`../Dev_copy_[date]`)? I don't understand the value of this. Your source (`.`) has all its history, so why are you manually creating snapshots?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to tell your shell to execute the `date` portion of your command, probably using backticks or `$(...)`, e.g.:

```
git clone -l -s -n . ../Dev_copy_`date "+%F_%T"`
```

Note that `date` is not connected to the date format string.

As a side note, running something like `git` with `sudo` is almost always a mistake. Try running this without `sudo`.

Also, please note that the copy you're cloning from in the current directory already contains a complete history of your commits. I'm not clear on what the benefit of manually creating a new copy with a manual timestamp is.